Azure SignalR: How to return ConnectionInfo when you don't know UserId in parameters yet?
I have a SignalR service that uses IHostedService to access SignalR on Azure. I'm trying to implement a Negotiate function that returns SignalRConnectionInfo. Problem is i need to pass the UserId into the ConnectionInfo but i don't know it yet when filling in parameters. I'm using .NET 8 in Isolated mode and following these Microsoft docs.
Function
[Function("Negotiate")]
public static string Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequestData req,
    [SignalRConnectionInfoInput(HubName = "SomeHub", UserId = "????")] string connectionInfo)
{
    Guid userId = // Get userId from database
    await signalRService.AddUserToGroupAll(userId);
    return connectionInfo; // How to get this when i don't know UserId in the parameters yet??
}

SignalRService
public class SignalRService(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    private ServiceHubContext _messageHubContext;

    public async Task AddUserToGroupAll(Guid userId)
    {
        await _messageHubContext.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(userId.ToString(), /** groupname **/);
    }

    #region IHostService Functions
    async Task IHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManagerBuilder()
            .WithOptions(o => o.ConnectionString = configuration[ConfigurationConstants.AzureSignalRConnectionString])
            .BuildServiceManager();
        _messageHubContext = await serviceManager.CreateHubContextAsync("SomeHub", cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _messageHubContext.DisposeAsync();
    }
    #endregion
}

My question is how do i return SignalRConnectionInfo in this case?
Thanks!

As mentioned in the MSDOC UserId is optional. Image

ServiceHubContext has a method called NegotiateAsync to which you can pass NegotiationOptions. You can set the UserId in there.
For example:
var negotiationResponse = await _serviceHubContext.NegotiateAsync(new NegotiationOptions { 
    UserId = userId.ToString() 
});
var connInfo = new SignalRConnectionInfo {
    AccessToken = negotiationResponse.AccessToken,
    Url = negotiationResponse.Url
};

And now you have your negotiated info with UserId.

Use below code to return ConnectionInfo in Isolated Azure functions.

I have created a .NET 8.0 isolated Azure function.
UserId is optional parameter as mentioned in MSDOC and ConnectionInfo can be returned even without passing UserId.

public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("negotiate");
    }

    [Function("negotiate")]
    public HttpResponseData Negotiate(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        [SignalRConnectionInfoInput(HubName = "HubValue", UserId ="")] MyConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"SignalR Connection URL = '{connectionInfo.Url}'");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        response.WriteString($"Connection URL = '{connectionInfo.Url}'");
        
        return response;
    }
}

public class MyConnectionInfo
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}

Console Response:
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801 Commit hash: N/A +5ac2f09758b98257e728dd1b5576ce5ea9ef68ff (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669

[2024-06-12T12:45:03.702Z] Found C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp18\FunctionApp18.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-06-12T12:45:14.003Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 12024) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-06-12T12:45:14.144Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        negotiate: [POST] http://localhost:7065/api/negotiate

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-06-12T12:45:19.095Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-06-12T12:45:20.088Z] Executing 'Functions.negotiate' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=c31883d3-4125-4cea-9c89-2c6456b76b26)
[2024-06-12T12:45:20.918Z] SignalR Connection URL = 'https://functionapp17.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=hubvalue'
[2024-06-12T12:45:21.022Z] Executed 'Functions.negotiate' (Succeeded, Id=c31883d3-4125-4cea-9c89-2c6456b76b26, Duration=968ms)

Output:


Can you please raise a new question including complete details regarding your requirement?

If you want to negotiate an anonymous session, you can get it from the SignalRService, so you don't need to pass UserId to your Negotiate function.
[Function("Negotiate")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Negotiate(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequestData req,
    FunctionContext context)
{
    var signalRService = (SignalRService)context.InstanceServices.GetService(typeof(SignalRService));
    var connectionInfo = await signalRService.GetSignalRConnectionInfo();

    return new OkObjectResult(connectionInfo);
}


@Kars Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]. That is anonymous, and is in your code. If you don't want to use IActionResult, just return connectionInfo; then.
